# Rmagick crop weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

This is using Rmagick v2.13.1 using standard install for imagemagick on macosx.

```
sudo port install tiff -macosx imagemagick +q8 +gs +wmf.
```

For some reason when using crop from rmagick inside carrierwave. If I hard code the dimensions to crop it works, however if I assign it to variables it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

There is no error message whatsoever, it just doesn't crop it.

```
def crop

  resize_to_limit(600,600)
  manipulate! do |img|

    print model.crop_x.to_i
    print model.crop_y.to_i
    print model.crop_w.to_i
    print model.crop_h.to_i

    x = model.crop_x.to_i
    y = model.crop_y.to_i
    width = model.crop_w.to_i
    height = model.crop_h.to_i

    print "\n"
    print "x class 1"
    print x.class

    print x,y,width,height

   # x = 205
    print "printing x class 2nd"
    print x.class
   # y = 232
   # width = 107
   # height = 107

    args = [x,y,width,height]


    img = img.crop(*args)
    print x,y,width,height
   # img.crop!(205,232,107,107)
    img
  end
end
```